# Complicated Regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have a very long string and I want to find the CAS number from that string which has some pattern as below:

> 2 to 7 digits-2 digits-1 digit

example :

`1154-12-6, 127946-96-2`

I am using following Regex to get this number:

```
str.match(/([0-9]{2,7})-([0-9]{2})-[0-9]/)
```

but for an example consisting "29022-11-5", it is giving me ["29022-11-5", "29022", "11"].

Please let me know how can I do it.

```js
console.log(

    "A long string with a number 29022-11-5 somewhere".match(/([0-9]{2,7})-([0-9]{2})-[0-9]/)
)    

// it is giving me ["29022-11-5", "29022", "11"].
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That looks like the correct answer to me.

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but it's not a duplicate of that one. It's still not clear to me what the OP is asking since his regular expression here seems to be working perfectly well.

Comment: I made you a snippet to show a [mcve]

Comment: I just want to find one number "29022-11-5" and not these values ["29022", "11"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `/g` flag to find all matches and use a word boundary `\b` to make sure your number is not part of a larger match. You might omit the capturing groups if you don't use them.

[`\b[0-9]{2,7}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Zu2Ssg/1/)

```js
let strings = [
  "29022-11-5",
  "1154-12-6, 127946-96-2"
];

let pattern = /([0-9]{2,7})-([0-9]{2})-[0-9]/g;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for if i am understanding this correctly:

`str.match(/[0-9]{2,7}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]/)`

You get `["29022-11-5", "29022", "11"]` because you have the `()` inside of your regex that means that it will group the result, but if you remove it you will get your result with out a group and that should be your wanted result.